# Can you make Ender Crystals do less damage?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been trying to find a way around Ender Crystal damage in my map I have been making. I want to make the Ender Crystals do less damage while keeping the overall player damage the same.
My first workaround involved using resistance against the Ender Crystals, then cancelling the resistance out for regular player damage by giving strength, however it seems that any resistance level above 5 makes the player invincible.

Is there a way to make Ender Crystals do less damage?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Try giving them blast resistance armor since that's where most of a Ender Crystal's damage comes from. Ah, and if you make it a certain durability or only allow it in those sections, it'd keep overall player damage the same.

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking to stop damage to the world, turn off mob briefing, meaning mobs or players can activate it unless by range. I hope this answered your question.